# Jquery - auto refresh specific div on page

Tags: php, jquery, refresh, setinterval

I would like to auto refresh a specific div (with the class 'autotest') every 3 seconds and I use this script to do so:

```
<div class="autotest">some variable</div>

setInterval(function() {
  $('.autotest').load(window.location.href + ' .autotest');
}, 3000);
```

and it kinda works but it includes the tag upon refreshing so it look like this:

```
<div class="autotest">
  <div class="autotest">some variable</div>
  <div class="autotest">some variable</div>
</div>
```

The first time it refreshes it ends up like above. The next time it refreshes it doesn't add more divs. On each refresh it updates the variable which is good.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a query parameter like "isajax=true" to your request to inform your php code that this is an ajax call and it does not need to include the surrounding div to the output.

In your php file you can simply add an if clause to send different outputs based on the query param:

```
if (!empty($_GET['isajax']) && $_GET['isajax'] == 'true') {
    // response without html tag
} else {
    // normal html response
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Alimo. I can't get your solution to work so I have tried something else which I have found in deep cyberspace:

    $('.autotest').load(location.href + ' .autotest>*', '');

Please notice the **>*,''**

It has the effect that it removes the inner content of the div tag and leaves it empty. Maybe it just need a minor correction?

Comment: If it works its fine! To get that solution to work, you can generate a url like this: var url = location.href + '?isajax=true'; and then use this url in your .load(url)

Comment: Hi @Alimo. I still can't get it to work. I have now tried 1) load(location.href + '?isajax=true') and 2) load(location.href + ' .autotest?isajax=true').

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help @Alimo. I couldn't get it to work but it was probably me. I decided to put my variable in another page and then simply load that one.

```
setInterval(function() {
  $('.autotest').load('autotest.php');
}, 3000);
```